# Formatter function doesn't work in XML Fragment

Tags: xml, sapui5, hana, formatter

There's a function called "formatCurrency" in my Controller file, but I can't get my XML Fragment to use it.

This is the function inside my Controller.js file:

```
formatCurrency : function(value){
    var d = ".";
    var t = ",";
    var c = 2;
    var p = "$";
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c;
    var s = value < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var i = parseInt(value = Math.abs(+value || 0).toFixed(2)) + "";
    var j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return p + s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(value - i).toFixed(2).slice(2) : "");
```

And this is the part of my XML Fragment file where I'm using it:

```
<Label text="Price" />
<ObjectNumber number = "{path : 'model>Price', formatter : '.formatCurrency'}" />
```

I read somewhere that I have to instantiate the fragment? I'm really new to this so I'm not sure how to do that. I did not know how to apply the examples I saw to my case.

PD: The function works perfectly when used in a normal View.xml file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the 4 steps which made it work for me:

#### Create the formatter

The formatter file is defined in ***webapp\model***.

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        formatNumber: function(value) {
            var result = "";
            if (value !== "undefined" && isNumeric(value)) {
                result = Number(value).toFixed(2);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
});
```

#### Extend the controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "myapp/html/model/formatter"
], function(Controller, formatter) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("myapp.html.controller", {
        formatter: formatter,
        
        // your code


    });
});
```

You can see the following in the code:

- Add the formatter class in the define section
- Extend the function arguments
- Define the formatter as a local variable which then can be referenced as **.formatter** in your view/fragments

#### Use the formatter in the fragment

```xml
<Text text="{path : 'results>value', formatter : '.formatter.formatNumber'}"/>
```

You can see the following in the code:

- I have a model named ***results*** and the attribute to display is ***value*** (but this is up to your code)
- It uses the ***expanded*** way to define the **Text** control **text** attribute

#### Include the fragment in your view

```xml
<ui:core.Fragment fragmentName="myapp.html.fragment.myfragment" type="XML"/>
```

Off course you should always make sure to get your property displayed without the formatter before adding it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the place it is used, I suspect that there could be a problem in the binding.Properties in named JSON models can be accessed like so (model>/Price instead of model>Price) - ([UI5 Property binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/guide/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html))

```
<Label text="Price" />
<ObjectNumber number = "{path : 'model>/Price', formatter : '.formatCurrency'}" />
```

Are you using this fragment in a Fiori elements application / for a dialog ? In case of manually using a fragment, it has to be instantiated. More importantly, you need to make sure you have instantiated the JSON model using `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel`

```
this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            Price: 23,
            .. : .., //Other properties in the model
            .. : ..
        }), "model");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call up your fragment via javascript, you have to "register" it for the view(otherthise bindings like i18n and formatter don't work):

```
sap.ui.core.Fragment.load({
    type: "XML",
    name: '<Namespace>.myFragment'
}).then(function (oFragment) {
    this.getView().addDependent(oFragment);
}.bind(this));
```

[Deprecated since version 1.58](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.xmlfragment):

```
if (!this.myFragment) {
    this.myFragment= sap.ui.core.Fragment.load(<Namespace>.myFragment',this);         
    this.getView().addDependent(this.myFragment, this);
}
```

See also docu:
[Example From Tutorial](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/4d/a72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a/content.htm?no_cache=true)
[addDependent](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/addDependent)

Comment: `sap.ui.xmlfragment` is deprecated since v1.58 (see: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.xmlfragment). now we should make use of `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load` instead.